# Create a list instance of a custom list using the web service api (Lists.asmx)

Tags: web-services

I've been looking a lot at the AddList and AddListFromFeature methods  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.addlistfromfeature(v=office.12).aspx) but can't really see if it is possible to create a list instance from a custom list using the web service api.

Anyone who know if it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in SharePoint 2010 and maybe can't do this in 2013. See the  [link to source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849945)